# Interacting with an element through xpath selector

Tags: xpath, cucumber, capybara

I see a lot of documentation and examples of people using xpath with capybara but for some reason I don't find anything on how to do the simplest thing... click a (button|link|whatever) identified by an xpath selector. How does one accomplish a step definition like:

```
Given /^I click the element identified by xpath "([^"]*)"$/ do |xpath_selector|
  click_button(xpath_selector)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually specify the xpath selector and click the element no matter what it is (button, link, div, etc), try:

```
page.find(:xpath, xpath_selector).click
```